# How to enforce the execution order of the tasks queued by setTimeout with 0 delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need to call some functions sequentially, and in order to force the framework to do a dirty check after each step, I employed setTimeout(func,0) to trigger the dirty check mechanism.

I know simply calling setTimeout one by one won't guarantee the passed async functions would be invoked in expected order, therefore I kludged the following solution:

```
function foo(arg){
  setTimeout(()=>console.log('executing task' + arg),0);
  console.log('on call stack' + arg);
  return foo;
}
```

I tried `foo(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)`, it works fine. But I'm not sure it will always work correctly.

So could anybody please help me with it!

---

@Steffomio's answer can definitely make the queued task deterministic, it also makes sure that each task has its own event loop ensuing.

Here is my adapted version:

```js
function queueTask(task) {
  var queue = [];
  function nextTask() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      queue.length && queue.shift()(); taskCount++;
      queue.length && nextTask();
    }, 0);
  }
  return (function pushTask(task) {
    queue.push(task);
    //After the first call trigger the timeout asynchrony
    if (queue.length === 1) { nextTask(); } 
    return pushTask;
  })(task);
}

//Test part below
function t(arg) { return function () { console.log('Task ' + arg); } }

var taskCount = 0;
var beginTime = Date.now();

queueTask(t(1))(t(2))(t(3))(t(4))(t(5))
  (t('a'))(t('b'))(t('c'))(t('d'))(t('e'))
  (t(1))(t(2))(t(3))(t(4))(t(5))
  (t('a'))(t('b'))(t('c'))(t('d'))(t('e'))  
  (function () { console.log(taskCount + ' tasks executed, Time elapsed: ' + (Date.now() - beginTime)); });
```

After some research I learned that the callback passed to `setTimeout` will be called by the system only when the call stack is cleared (no more code on it), thus the actual execution of queued tasks won't start until the the queuing is done, and if we queue several 0-delay timeout tasks linearly, when the next event loop starts, they will all be executed in a single run. That is not what I want! So, calling `setTimeout` inside the callback of the preceding `setTimeout` is the only way so far I know to enforce tick by tick tasks scheduling.

For better understanding, please reference the talk ["What the heck is the event loop anyway"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) given by Philip Roberts at JSConf EU 2014

Comment: Try [Promise mechanism](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a queue:

```
q = [];
addQueue(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
addQueue('a')('b')('d');
addQueue(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
addQueue('a')('b')('d');
addQueue(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
addQueue('a')('b')('d');

function queue(){
    if(q.length){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('queue: ' + q.shift()); 
            q.length && queue();
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function addQueue(n){
    if(q.length){
        q.push(n);
    }else{
        q.push(n);
        queue();
    }
    return addQueue;
}
```

for testing copy and paste code to console.

Comment: I'm not sure this will definitely work, it is exactly my question. MDN said: "Because even though setTimeout was called with a delay of zero, it's placed on a queue and scheduled to run at the next opportunity, not immediately. Currently executing code must complete before functions on the queue are executed, __the resulting execution order may not be as expected.__" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: Sounds like angularJs framework problems. If so, you simply have to add the function instead the example-numbers to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

May be this kind of approach works for you

```
function foo(args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // your code based on args
      if (args.length) {
         console.log("processing", args[0]);
         resolve(args.slice(1, args.length));
      } else {
         reject("finished");
      }
  }).then(args => {
     return foo(args);
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log("Tasks completed...");
  });
}

foo([1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]);
```

Output should be something like :

```
processing 1
processing 2
processing 3
processing 4
processing 5
Tasks completed...
```

Comment: This is good, but I really need to call setTimeout(f,0) to trigger the dirty checking